# Custom Field Limit Error on Installation of Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

I'm running into an issue where in attempting to install a managed package I get an installation error about hitting the custom field limit.

My understanding of Managed Package is that it doesn't count against the field limit.  I installed fine on another environment that was clean of custom fields and was able to verify that the package's installation didn't add any fields counted to the limit.

Does anyone have any insight to what's going on here?

Comment: Hi Steve, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, like the specific error message and the kind of org you've installed your package to, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer that you'll find helpful.

Comment: Which edition are you using to install this package? If it is Personal Edition or Contact Manager Edition, you might be running into the limitations imposed by those editions. They allow a limited number of custom fields per object (5 and 25 fields, respectively). 

What might be happening is that the package is trying to add more fields to a standard object (eg: Account), and transpassing this limit.

I am not sure about this though.